# Exporting Data from Excel to phpmyadmin SQL database

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

I would appreciate some help solving problems accessing a MySQL database from Excel.

I've created the database in phpmyadmin. I've also been able to manually import data via a CSV file into the SQL database on phhpmyadmin.

So, I'm sure that I've got the right IP address, user ID and password for the database.

I've also read various posts about how to configure ODBC connections from Windows to SQL and I think I've followed the right instructions.

However, I can't seem to get the code to work from VBA. I keep getting various errors.

Here's the code I've been using, minus the actual database names and User IDs.

```
Private Sub cmdInsertData_Click()
Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim Pwd As String
Dim SQLStr As String
Dim Svr_Nm As String
Dim UID As String
Dim Dbs_Nm As String

' Input Parameters
Pwd = "mypassword"
UID = "myuser"
srvr_nm = "xxx.xxx.xx.xx:yyyy"
Dbs_Nm = "myname"
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
SQLStr = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver};"
SQLStr = SQLStr & "SERVER=" & srvr_nm & ";DATABASE=" & Dbs_Nm & ";USER=" & UID & ";PASSWORD=" & Pwd & ";Option=3"
oConn.Open SQLStr

MsgBox "Connected to " & Dbs_Nm & " via " & srvr_nm
End Sub
```

I've reset the code as follows. The error message is generated by the line "oConn.Open SQLStr". The error generated is

Run-time error ‘-2147467259 (80004005)’:
[MySQL][ODBC 5.3(a) Driver]Unknown MySQL server host ‘209.159.152.202:2083’ (0)

New Code:

```
Private Sub CheckConnection()
Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim Pwd As String
Dim SQLStr As String
Dim Svr_Nm As String
Dim Usr_ID As String
Dim Dbs_Nm As String

' Input Parameters
Pwd = "mypassword"
Usr_ID = "myID"
srvr_nm = "209.159.152.202:2083"
Dbs_Nm = "mydatabase"
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
SQLStr = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver};"
SQLStr = SQLStr & "SERVER=" & srvr_nm & ";DATABASE=" & Dbs_Nm & ";USER=" & Usr_ID & ";PASSWORD=" & Pwd & ";Option=3"
oConn.Open SQLStr

MsgBox "Connected to " & Dbs_Nm & " via " & srvr_nm
End Sub
```

Thanks for the suggestion about adding the Port= as a separate variable. I've tried that however (see new code) and it still doesn't work.

```
Private Sub CheckConnection()
Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim Pwd As String
Dim SQLStr As String
Dim Svr_Nm As String
Dim Usr_ID As String
Dim Dbs_Nm As String
Dim Port_Nm As String

' Input Parameters
Pwd = "mypassword"
Usr_ID = "myID"
Svr_Nm = "209.159.152.202"
Dbs_Nm = "mydatabase"
Port_Nm = "2083"
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
SQLStr = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver};"
SQLStr = SQLStr & "Server=" & Svr_Nm & ";Port=" & Port_Nm & ";Database=" & Dbs_Nm & ";User=" & Usr_ID & ";Password=" & Pwd & ";Option=3"
oConn.Open SQLStr

MsgBox "Connected to: " & Dbs_Nm & " via " & Svr_Nm
End Sub
```

I still get the same error message at the same place.

Comment: "various errors" is not a useful description of your problem: it's better to include the exact error message(s), and indicate which lines trigger them.

Comment: Hello, the precise error message is: Run-time error ‘-2147467259 (80004005)’:
[MySQL][ODBC 5.3(a) Driver]Unknown MySQL server host ‘209.159.152.202:2083’ (0)

Comment: Try Port as a separate parameter - it doesn't go  on the end of the IP address.  https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/

Comment: I'm wondering whether I need to something besides installing the ODBC drivers in Windows to make the connect work. Does anyone have ideas?

Comment: Turns out that one of the problems I was having is that I needed to Whitelist the various IP addresses I was using to access the database. I was using different computer in separate locations, hence multiple IPs.

Comment: All was resolved once the whitelist was taken care of.